# Resteasy: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss7.x, resteasy, web.xml

I have Resteasy servlet and listener configured in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Auto scan REST service -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- this should be the same URL pattern as the servlet-mapping property -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/rest</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

When I trying to deploy EAR on JBoss-as-web-7.0.0.Final I get error:

> org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext

My EAR contains war and EJB jar inside, if it have a meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** you need to servlet api dependency in your project as below:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

OR

add `javax.servlet-3.0.jar` file in your classpath.

**2)** Go to `<JBOSS-HOME>/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`

Find the element
`<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" />`

and replace it by

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
  <global-modules>
       <module name="javaee.api" slot="main"/> 
  </global-modules>
</subsystem>`
```

**3)** Go to
`JBoss\jboss-eap-6.1\modules\system\layers\base\javax\servlet\api\main`

include JAR
`jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar`

**I recommend you to use Jboss AS 7.1.1.Final version only instead of 7.0.0 Final.**

Comment: I have 4 pom.xml files in my project. In the root folder, in the appname-web, in the appname-ejb and in the appname-ear. I tried to add servlet api dependency in each of this pom.xml, in rotation.  But error remains the same.  Also I tried put javax.servlet-3.0.jar in JBOSS_HOME/standalone/lib but it not helped.

Comment: If you are using servlet in all of these above locations then you have to add the servlet dependency in it(all 4 files).

Comment: I have added servlet dependency in all 4 files, but the error is the same.

Comment: Thank you, all works with version 2.5 of servlet api.