# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for MultipartFormDataInputImpl while using resteasy

Tags: java, web-services, maven, resteasy

I am using resteasy to provide a webservice for file uploads. I have a few webservices ready (GET service to return some list of objects as json etc) which all work. However, when trying to do some file upload via postman (Content-Type is set to multipart/form-data;boundary="XXXX") I get the following error on the server side:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/providers/multipart/MultipartFormDataInputImpl
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataReader.readFrom(MultipartFormDataReader.java:54)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartFormDataReader.readFrom(MultipartFormDataReader.java:23)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:59)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerReaderInterceptorContext.readFrom(ServerReaderInterceptorContext.java:62)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:51)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.interceptors.encoding.GZIPDecodingInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(GZIPDecodingInterceptor.java:59)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractReaderInterceptorContext.java:53)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MessageBodyParameterInjector.inject(MessageBodyParameterInjector.java:150)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.injectArguments(MethodInjectorImpl.java:89)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:112)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:288)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:242)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:229)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179)
at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220)
at org.tynamo.resteasy.ResteasyRequestFilter.service(ResteasyRequestFilter.java:98)
at $HttpServletRequestFilter_62c2163ae572.service(Unknown Source)
at $HttpServletRequestHandler_62c2163ae576.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
at $HttpServletRequestFilter_62c2163ae56f.service(Unknown Source)
at $HttpServletRequestHandler_62c2163ae576.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:796)
at $HttpServletRequestHandler_62c2163ae576.service(Unknown Source)
at $HttpServletRequestHandler_62c2163ae56e.service(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My relevant pom section looks like this:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tynamo</groupId>
        <artifactId>tapestry-resteasy</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

First I thought it might have something to do with the library and the classpath, so I tried compile (but learned this is the default so it might not have an impact). I also checked similar issues ([Resteasy: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838965/resteasy-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-servlet-servletcontext)) but found that I included the javax.servlet-api already.

Also, if I try to switch to version 2.3.10.Final for the resteasy-multipart-provider I even get an Exception (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MultipartFormDataInput) at application start up.

So can anyone give me a hint on where the error might come from?

Answer (score 0):

As of now the issue appears to be fixed by adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
```